# PHP UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am currently using Amazon AWS' Elasticbeanstalk running PHP 5.5 on 64bit Amazon Linux Server. My service basically allows its users to upload files to the server, process that currently works perfectly well. The problem comes when, after thousands of uploads, my server starts rejecting every single upload throwing an UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE error (Error 7).

I know the problem is not that I don't have permission to write on the directory because the process works well until **something happens** and I start getting this error. I also know my server is not full, I just checked it and its using only 254MB of disk space. Also, when I restart the app server, I can start uploading files again.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after months of research it seems the answer relied in the fact that Amazon instances only have 8GB of disk space by default and about 7GB were occupied by the default AMI installation. My disk partition was getting full after a little amount of time and therefore php was not able to write to disk. The solution relied in attaching EBS Volumes to the instances, allowing php to write in bigger partitions (up to 1024GB).

http://aws.amazon.com/es/ebs/